# Splitting a comma delimited field for a large amount of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to migrate data from one schema to another and am having some issues with splitting a comma delimited field.

**S1: Source Database**

**S2: Destination Database**

S1 has a field called **ownerUserIDList** which links to **AMID** in S2, the problem is that S2 only allows 1 value in this field whereas S1 can have multiple and is comma delimited in the database so my plan is to split the field and update S2 with the last element of the split.

Problem is that it takes far too long and is constantly timing out. The table has about 600k rows. I have tried a few methods that i have found on SO but none really seem to be that fast for a large data-set.

All of the below examples will be made into an update statement for the actual migration of data, these were just to compare run timings.

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT TOP 100000 CASE 
        WHEN ownerUserIDList LIKE '%,%' THEN SUBSTRING( ownerUserIDList , LEN(ownerUserIDList) -  CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(ownerUserIDList)) + 2  , LEN(ownerUserIDList)  )
        ELSE ownerUserIDList
    END
FROM S1.UserTable WHERE ownerUserIDList != '' AND ownerUserIDList IS NOT NULL
```

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 2359 ms,  elapsed time =
>   728479 ms.

**Method2:**

```
SELECT TOP 100000 value 
FROM S1.UserTable
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ownerUserIDList, ',') 
    WHERE ownerUserIDList != '' AND ownerUserIDList IS NOT NULL
GO
```

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 1719 ms,  elapsed time =
>   399817 ms.

Both of these are quite slow considering i will have to run similar queries on multiple even larger tables. Are there any other methods for splitting these fields that would work a bit quicker?

The table structures are quite simple:

**S1**:

```
UserID    ownerUserIDList   S2_AMID
---------------------------------------
1           20              1
2           20, 21, 23      4
3           21, 22, 23      4
```

**S2**:

```
AMID    S1_UserID
-----------------
1       20
2       21
3       22
4       23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really only want the last entry, try this. You can add clause to avoid empty or single entry lists.

```
declare @t table(UserID int, OwnerID varchar(50))
insert @t values (1,'1,2,3'),(2,'3,4,5'),(3,'6,7,8')
select *, left(reverse(ownerID),CHARINDEX(',',reverse(ownerID))-1) from @t
```

This is very close to your first option but I doubt you will get closer. Maybe a CLI function? I'll leave it up to someone else to code that up.

Comment: This worked, took 6 seconds to create the links after fiddling around with the update query a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server is not good at manipulating strings, if your primary goal is to get the best performance for splitting the string, you can try `CLR` function.

You can get more details on the `CLR` function [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1665/sql-server-clr-and-sql-split-functions-to-parse-a-delimited-string/)

Comment: I have never used CLR functions before i don't have time to learn them for this task, but thanks for this will be useful going forward.